# Why getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while unit testing  the controller

Tags: java, spring

Why am I getting this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerAdapter]
>   is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

```
   public class MyControllerIntegrationTest {
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyControllerIntegrationTest.class);
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private MockHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;
private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;
private TestExceptionController controller;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);

    controller = new TestExceptionController();
}
```

I am trying to run the above code. My application context is loaded and getting the above exception message. Please guide, should I add some bean definition in bean definition file?

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory?  You have no bean of type `HandlerAdapter` in your test's context.  You should show us the whole test, including class annotations, plus the test context file.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [the `ApplicationContextAware` interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html), or change your code to directly inject the HandlerAdapter (by moving the `@Autowired` annotation to that field) instead of getting it from the app context. (Unless it's a prototype, not a singleton, and you really need a new instance on every unit test.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when going from Spring 3.0.7 to Spring 3.1.

I solved it using this answer: [How to unit test a Spring MVC annotated controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916344/990890)