# Testing spring mvc controller having the view with tiles configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I dont know how to test a controller that has view with tiles configuration.

Below is the unit test case written

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml", "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class)
public class BankControllerTest {

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    private BankController controller;


    private ModelAndView handle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        final HandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerMapping.class);
        final HandlerExecutionChain handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
        Assert.assertNotNull("No handler found for request, check you request mapping", handler);
        final Object controller = handler.getHandler();
        for (final HandlerInterceptor interceptor : handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getInterceptors()) {
            if (!interceptor.preHandle(request, response, controller)) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        this.handlerAdapter = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerAdapter.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void banksList() throws Exception {
        request.setRequestURI("/banksList.do");
        request.setMethod("GET");
        final ModelAndView mav = handle(request, response);
        // assertViewName(mav, "banksList");
        // assertAndReturnModelAttributeOfType(mav, "banksList",
        // BankList.class);
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/sach-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml]
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2c1e6b] to prepare test instance [com.myapp.simulator.controller.BankControllerTest@811c88]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tiles-definitions.xml]; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: tiles.apache.org
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: tiles.apache.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 34 more
```

How to overcome this error. What is the testing approach for controller. do i need to use any other framework in order to write testcases for my controllers

Answer (score 1):

Put the `lazy-init="true"` for tiles bean configuration as below.

```
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" lazy-init="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to test. If you are just making sure that the tile view names are correct, then it is correct you don't have to use Spring Configuration. However if you want to see if a view is resolved or check model attributes, responses, etc then Spring has a MVC testing framework. It was a standalone, but it is now part of 3.2. So if you are using Spring 3 you might want to look at the tests in [SpringMVC Showcase](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase). I haven't tested it yet with Tiles, but it does have the ability to set a view resolver so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not load a spring context with beans that requires an web container.

If you only want to test the controllers, then I recommend real Unit test, without Spring Context. That mean you need to create mocks for the classes that are required by your controller.

Comment: Can you help me in pointing to a blog where i can find an example

Comment: http://blog.vergiss-blackjack.de/2010/04/unit-testing-a-spring-controller/,   Mocking framework: http://code.google.com/p/mockito/  or http://www.jmock.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401128/how-to-unit-test-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-pathvariable

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following to load test cases in spring boot with tiles as an example

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)   
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class, TestConfigurtaion.class})   
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testCase{

    }   
}
```

Then another class for tiles configuration

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfigurtaion {

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/tiles.xml" });
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}
```