# Calling Spring Based web application Classes from POJO

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, pojo

I have a WEB Application. I was asked to Call a Class (Service) inside the Spring application from a POJO.

The Service is not exposed either as Webservice or REST. I was just the application as a jar. I had to add this to build path and call the service.

Will it work??

Am terribly confused!

Comment: Can you please provide some code examples so we can determine what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a lot of detail in here, but I'm assuming this is a Spring application using Spring MVC, in which case yes, there's no reason why you can't call the service as a class.

This is why you can use JUnit to test @Controller classes in Spring, it's literally just a POJO.

Link below as an example of how to do this.

[How to unit test a Spring MVC controller using @PathVariable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401128/how-to-unit-test-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-pathvariable)

Answer (score 1):

If your pojo is a Spring Bean, then you can just autowire the service like this:

```
public class YourPojo {
   @Autowired
   YourService yourService; 
}
```

You might consider making your Pojo a Spring Bean by annotationg it with @Component,
or declaring it in your ApplicationContext.xml

If not, you get your service like this if you have a request object:

```
ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();
ApplicationContext ac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);
YourService yourService = ac.getBean("yourService");
```