# Junit test method - cannot resolve symbol '.ok()'

Tags: java, rest, junit

Hello I want to use method `response` in my **junit** `test` method but I have an error:
`cannot resolve symbol 'response'`

What is a reason or maybe u know other method which can I replace in this place?

This is my method:

```
@PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> addPeopleToTeam(@PathVariable Long teamId, @PathVariable Long personId) {
    TeamsAndPersonsId teamsAndPersonsId = new TeamsAndPersonsId(personId, teamId);
    teamService.findTeamById(teamsAndPersonsId.getTeamId());
    personService.findById(teamsAndPersonsId.getPersonId());
    teamService.addPersonsToTeams(personId, teamId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(teamsAndPersonsId);

}
```

And here is my test code:

```
@Test
    public void shouldAddPersonToTeam() throws Exception {
        // Given
        TeamDto teamDto = prepareTeamDto();
        PersonDto personDto = preparePersonDto();
        // When
        when(teamService.createTeam(teamDto)).thenReturn(Response.ok().build());
        when(personService.addPerson(personDto)).thenReturn(Response.ok().build());
        // than
        mockMvc.perform(post("/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}", 1, 1))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

This element (Reponse.ok().build()); after thenReturn deosn't work.

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: method Response is red underscore and i can;t implement method is unrecognizable. This method should be implements from coyote?When i add coyote implementation - ok() is unrecognizable

Comment: may be you should change that from `Reponse` to `Response`? notice the missing `s`

Comment: Sorry there is Response but in this case is not recognize element .ok()

Comment: what is your import statement for that `Response`? do you use an IDE? this should be fairly simple to understand

Comment: import org.apache.coyote.Response; - this is my iport i Use Intelij

Comment: it's as simple as you are not importing the correct `Response` class - you should import the one from `Spring-test-mvc` ;)

Comment: Thanks but problem is that i don't have import from spring-test-mvc. I have only coyote, catalina, xml and nativesandbox. All of this imports are wrongs

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that import of `Response` is NOT correct.

On a separate note, production class is using `ResponseEntity.ok(teamsAndPersonsId)` but your unit test case is Mocking `Response` class. Make sure that you are using mock object of the same class in your unit test case.

Refer [How to unit test a Spring MVC controller using @PathVariable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401128/how-to-unit-test-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-pathvariable) for a sample test.

Comment: I have two mocks in my test class: 
 private TeamService teamService;
 
 private PersonService personService;